# Make a project more OO Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I've made a 12 by 12 table that runs in the same program, but i'd like to make it OO so that i can put the "public static void main" in another "testfile" and it will still run properly..i'm having some problems with the OO approach and i really need help...This is what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class PlayingArea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many regions would you like (2- 4)");
        int region = input.nextInt();
        String letters = "";
        while(letters.length() < 2) {
            if (region == 4) {
                letters= "EFGH";
            }
            if (region == 3) {
                letters= "EFG";
            } else if (region == 2) {
                letters= "EF";
            } else if (region < 2) {
                System.out.println("You inputed a wrong value, try again...");
            }
        }
        int N = letters.length();
        char [][] letter = new char[12][12];

        for (int j = 0; j < letter.length; j++) {

            for(int i=0; i < letter.length; i++) {
                letter[i][j] = letters.charAt(r.nextInt(N)) ;
            }
        }

        for (char[] letterRow : letter)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letterRow));
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand the question, you are looking to have a test class of some sort that has `static void main`, which then creates an instance of `PlayingArea` ? Is this homework?

Comment: I'm trying to make a game :) yeah, that's exactly what i want :D

Comment: Cool, looks like there are a couple good answers below already. With questions around the context of a game like this, it may be helpful to mention briefly that it is (or is not) homework. People will help either way, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're relatively new to java then you're doing quite well. Be aware there is an infinite loop in your program (fixed below) if you enter a number outside of 2-4.

Firstly, your class `PlayingArea` needs some member variables to represent state.

The first one is the `String letters` (EF or EFG or EFGH), which is initialized via a constructor in the code below.

The second one is the `char[][] grid` (renamed from `letter` in your code) which is assigned a value in the `populate()` method, which puts letters into the grid.

The other method, `gridAsString()` does just that.

The `public static void main` can easily now be moved to another class, if you like.

Have fun.

```
public class PlayingArea {
    private String letters;
    private char[][] grid;

    public PlayingArea(String letters) {
        this.letters = letters;
    }

    public void populate() {
        int n = letters.length();
        grid = new char[12][12];

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
                grid[i][j] = letters.charAt(r.nextInt(n));
            }
        }

    }

    public String gridAsString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char[] letterRow : grid) {
            sb.append(Arrays.toString(letterRow)).append('\n');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many regions would you like (2- 4)");
        String letters = "";
        while (letters.length() < 2) {
            int region = input.nextInt();
            if (region == 4) {
                letters = "EFGH";
            } else if (region == 3) {
                letters = "EFG";
            } else if (region == 2) {
                letters = "EF";
            } else {
                System.out.println("You inputed a wrong value, try again...");
            }
        }
        PlayingArea playingArea = new PlayingArea(letters);
        playingArea.populate();
        System.out.println(playingArea.gridAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer :D if it's not too difficult for you can you explain the part of "private String gridAsString()" ??

Comment: Hi Tommon, no worries, methods `populate` and `gridAsString` should actually be `public`. The latter function generates a String over multiple lines that you can print to sout. A `StringBuilder` is a common way to build up a big String, although you could have also used a plain `String result = "";` and then in the for loop `result += Arrays.toString(letterRow)) + '\n';` to then `return result;`. One important OO concept is encapsulation, and the `PlayingArea` class "hides" the internal data representation and provides public functions like `gridAsString` to the outside world.

Comment: Thanks :) but now if it's a string i won't be able to change all characters of 'E' (for example) to another character will I..?

Comment: True, so in that case you could provide another public method for example changeLettersFromTo(char letterFrom, char letterTo).

Comment: Sorry for all the bothering...but you sort of confused me now xD